# Angular7: unable to set {responseType: 'text'}

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, chunked

**Scenario**: 
Upon an API call from Angular7, i am calling Node (via express) and returning chunked data of type string - I want to capture this string data and display it as string

**Server-side:**
From Node backend, the data is being sent is 'text' and not json... the data is sent via multiple res.write('some strings') statements

**client-side in Angular:**
I want an observable to process this data...

1. when i don't mention any responseType [return this.http.get(this.streamURL );]... i get error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 12
>       at JSON.parse ()

[image: the error on stackBlitz and similar error at compile time on ng serve]

2. when i don't mention responseType as 'text [return this.http.get(this.streamURL , { responseType: 'text'});]... i get error at compile time:

> ERROR in src/app/myS.service.ts(24,54): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is
>   not assignable to type '"json"'

how can i capture 'text' data from my Node JS backend... i am using npm cors in my Node so no CORS errors there

**Demo code** available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-44sess

My **Back-end** is in the snippet below:

```js
app.get('/obs/responseWrite', cors(), function(req, res){
  var j=0;
  
  const headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'text',     
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
  };
  res.writeHead(200,headers);
  
  for(var i=0; i<50000; i++){
    /* setInterval(function() {    res.write("returning j:["+ j + "]. "); j=j+1; if(j>=100){res.end();} }, 1000); */
    var myObj =  { return : i };
    var myStr= JSON.stringify(myObj);
    console.log(myStr);
    res.write(myStr);
  }
  setInterval(function() {    res.end(); }, 15000);
  
});
```

Comment: try this once `return this.http.get(this.streamURL , { responseType: 'text'});` remove any.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I always use the following patterns in this case:

```js
returnObservable(): Observable<any> {
  const requestOptions: Object = {
    /* other options here */
    responseType: 'text'
  }
  return this.http.get<any>(this.streamURL , requestOptions);
}
```

Hope it answers your question!

Comment: I set responseType as below as it is working.

return this.httpClient.get<any>(
      `${environment.baseApiUrl}/getResonseAsText`, { params: queryParams, headers: headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json'});

For ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Comment: @Ieremias Viorel Life saver! I used this for excel download. And perfectly worked.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use return generic type. In documentation generic type is only for 'json'. This mean you need use get like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.streamURL, { responseType: "text"});
```

See in documentation https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get 
You are interest Overload #11 and now you are using Overload #13

Finally this is link for your code with update: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv1tkl?file=src/app/myS.service.ts

**EDIT 1**

I pasted wrong link to stackblitz. Correct above.

Comment: as i wrote above (point #2)... when i do this, i get error and program doesn't compile... [ERROR in src/app/myS.service.ts(24,54): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"']

Comment: @AIqbalRaj check my example in stackblitz. I add wep-api and i dont get error that you mention.

Comment: i got the error and updated the question with it - in my local angular, i got error on "ng serve" also

Comment: the question clearly said Angular 7, and this gives "No overload matches this call" error. the accepted answer above works fine.

Comment: Thanks!  This should be the accepted answer IMO.