# HttpErrorResponse - Cannot get the text/html response from server

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular7, angular-httpclient

I have an issue to get the http response from my server.
I want to reproduce a authentication login with HttpClient into my login.service.ts file.

I tried 2 last hours to find a solution but nothing is working...

Here is the code i use for it :

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', null, {headers: {
        'x-login': 'admin', 
        'x-password': '8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918'}})
  .subscribe(myToken => console.log(myToken));
  }
}
```

I used PostMan to test the login and password, */auth* respond a token : *653db89e-b80e-47f8-834a-62275b04fcbb*.

The Content-Type is not a *JSON* response, this is a *text/html; charset=utf-8* and i think that is maybe the problem but I don't really know.

The error is :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 201, statusText: "Created", url: "http://localhost:3000/auth", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "08951337-479a-4e53-8b1b-823d29d89139"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/auth"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 201
statusText: "Created"
url: "http://localhost:3000/auth"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Any help is welcome !

I try to learn Angular 7, if what I say is not clear, 
do not hesitate to ask me for more informations.

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried `this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', null, {headers: { ... }, responseType: "text" })` ?

Comment: this might get you through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627244/angular7-unable-to-set-responsetype-text

Comment: I used the proposal of @Kos and added the ```reponseType: "text"``` parameter, thanks to both of you, it worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the `reponseType: "text"` parameter to my *post()* and it worked !
That is the full operation :

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', null, {headers: {
        'x-login': 'admin', 
        'x-password': '8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918'},
responseType: "text" })
.subscribe(myToken => console.log(myToken)); // Output : 43307067-0c23-47ae-8085-402959e1f157
```